# Count how many rsync process are running on unix machine

Tags: unix, rsync, process

I am using Unix machine

```
$ uname -a
SunOS machine-name 5.10 Generic_127112-11 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

How would I get the number of `rsync` process running on my `unix` box.
I tried

```
$ ps -ef | grep rsync
```

But it showing me the list of all `rsync` processes.
Is there any way to get exact number of `rsync` process running?.

in `/etc/rsyncd.conf`
I have set `max_connections=150`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
ps -ef | grep rsync | wc -l
```

`wc -l` will count lines.  You should have one line per rsync process.

Comment: careful with that.. `ps -ef | grep rsync` also returns the running grep command, so `wc -l` may return "1" even if no rsync process is running (at least on my linux box it does) -> use `ps -ef | grep rsync | grep -v grep | wc -l` instead